# Python: Append to an empty string

Tags: python, variables

I'm working on a project, currently, and I would like to add characters/gr

```
barfoo = ""
# Something that adds 'hel' to barfoo?
# Something that adds 'lo' to barfoo?
print(barfoo)
> 'hello'
```

How would I do such a thing? Note that I am aware of adding it to a list and simply 'condensing' it, but I would like to know if there is an easier method.

Comment: You can't initialize what's not defined.

Comment: You could initialise it with an empty string `barfoo = ""`, which would result in `hi` after appending h and i. However, by assigning the empty string to the variable `barfoo`, you are defining the variable.

Comment: I think _"I want to initialize a string but not define it"_ is `xXIronmanXx`'s way of saying that he wants "an empty string" (or initialize `barfoo` to an empty string).

Comment: Strings are *immutable*. You can reassign what a name points to, but not append to a string.

Comment: So you can't append @ChristophTerasa?

Comment: @AGNGazer Yes! Sorry, I'm a rookie to Python

Comment: You cannot append to a string, but you can assign the name `barfoo` to a new string, which is the concatenation of two strings: `barfoo = barfoo + "baz"`, or the shorthand variant `barfoo += "baz"`.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I got it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either start with an empty string and concatenate, or start with an empty list and join.

```
barfoo = ''
barfoo += 'h'
barfoo += 'i'
print(barfoo)
```

...

```
barfoo = []
barfoo.append('h')
barfoo.append('i')
print(''.join(barfoo))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I thought `+=` and `-=` was for numbers only

Comment: @xXIronmanXx: They are for any type that implements either them or `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
barfoo = ""
barfoo = barfoo + 'H'
barfoo = barfoo + 'I'
```